# Unable to parse output of a function

Tags: bash, shell-script, io, daemon

I am writing a Bash script that is supposed to run other daemonized Bash scripts, called servlets.

The function I am inquiring about is `getStatus`:

```
getStatus() {
     servletToCheck="$@"
     if [ "$(ps -aux | grep \"$(whoami)\" | grep \"${servletToCheck}\" | grep -v \"grep\" | wc -l)" -eq 0 ]; then
        echo -n "Offline"
     else
        echo -n "Online"
     fi
}
```

What it *should* be doing is checking if the arguments are a running process owned by the user, and output `Online` if it is, `Offline` otherwise.
Now, this function seems to be working **perfectly**. The problem seems to be with how I'm **parsing** it:

```
if [ "$(getStatus ${tbnServlet})" == "Online" ]; then
    outSuccess "Started servlet: ${tbnServlet}"
    exit 0
else
    outWarning "Failed to start servlet: ${tbnServlet}"
    exit 3
fi
```

Strangely, even when the servlet is up and running, it says it `Failed to start/stop servlet`, and running a function that lists the servlets lists all of them as offline, even when they aren't.

**What is the issue, and how can I correct it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is too complex for this basic job...

```
pgrep -u $USER "$tbnServlet" >/dev/null && echo "Started servlet: $tbnServlet" || echo "Failed to start servlet: $tbnServlet"
```

Comment: Apparently using pgrep fixed it. +1